# Rabbitmq - websocket - consumer - send message only to user with given user_id

Tags: php, websocket, rabbitmq

I have a question. I am working with Rabbitmq for some time but I always used Rabbimq with public available messages via WebSocket (for example, long update that lasts about one hour, frontend got WebSocket connection to Rabbimq, and few consumers are sending notifications about progress (for example. 5%, 10%, 15% - module A finished, 20%, etc). In that example messages send via WebSocket (consumer => rabbimq => WebSocket in browser) should be publicly available (everyone should see them).

But what I if want that only specific WebSocket will receive messages sent by the consumer? (for example, only user_id = 99 because it is private message / private notification).

How to do this? It is possible to send user_id specific messages from consumer => rabbitmq => websocket (browser)?

Is there a way to, for example, during JS Websocket init connection send user_id to Rabbitmq and then Rabbitmq will send only messages which match given user_id?

For example:

`on-js-websocket-connect send { user_id: 99 }`

`on-consumer-message send { user_id: 99, message: "Hi, how are you?" }`

And Rabbitmq will dispatch this message only to one specific WebSocket (or to many WebSocket if user_id match - for example, the user got opened many tabs in browser).

Comment: was wondering the same thing, ended up here but no Answers